# Android/Monodroid HorizontalScrollview on Drag

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a horizontalscrollview in my applictation and I want to call the ondrag action to get the current scrollposition. But I got the following error:

My code

```
sv.Drag += delegate(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e) {
    //do something
};
```

the error:

The nested type DragEventArgs does not exist in the type Android.Views.View

Perhaps the wrong namespace? I don't know. :/

Comment: Or can I register a gesture?

Comment: Hey... Are you able to resolve this error. I am getting this error. Any comments on this.